# no lines available in input by reading url in vector

Tags: r, csv, rcurl

I created a vector do download csv from the web :

```
> head(URLs)

> [1]
> "https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?30&filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&type=cal&bubble=true&token=4e5i7nyzf9nhrunjgurg&calPeriod=-1&start=2007-01-01%200:0&end=2007-02-01%200:0"
> [2]
> "https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?30&filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&type=cal&bubble=true&token=4e5i7nyzf9nhrunjgurg&calPeriod=-1&start=2007-02-01%200:0&end=2007-03-01%200:0"
> [3]
> "https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?30&filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&type=cal&bubble=true&token=4e5i7nyzf9nhrunjgurg&calPeriod=-1&start=2007-03-01%200:0&end=2007-04-01%200:0"
> [4]
> "https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?30&filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&type=cal&bubble=true&token=4e5i7nyzf9nhrunjgurg&calPeriod=-1&start=2007-04-01%200:0&end=2007-05-01%200:0"
> [5]
> "https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?30&filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&type=cal&bubble=true&token=4e5i7nyzf9nhrunjgurg&calPeriod=-1&start=2007-05-01%200:0&end=2007-06-01%200:0"
> [6]
> "https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?30&filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&type=cal&bubble=true&token=4e5i7nyzf9nhrunjgurg&calPeriod=-1&start=2007-06-01%200:0&end=2007-07-01%200:0"
```

and I'm trying to get the csv from it, ex:

```
one = getURL(URLs[1])
read.csv(one)
```

and i receive the following error :

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : no lines available in input
```

can someone give a hint ?

Best Regards

Comment: not sure what geturl does but it is unnecessary, `read.csv('http....csv')` works

Comment: Thank you, but how do I put that link as a variable name and working ?

Comment: because is a vector of links, it has hundreds

Comment: I could not download a single csv with content in it, which is what would lead to the error you describe. "No lines in input" means the machine is reading an empty csv.
Are you sure the query is well-formatted and the parametter filter for csv with actual content? Has the token expired already?

Comment: When I open the link I get the right csv downloaded in browser, but is being hard to get it on rstudio ... Anybody knows how to do it ?